# genshi template greater than operator

Tags: javascript, turbogears2, genshi

I am using Genshi template engine in the Turbogears2 web framework. While writing the simple *javascript if statement*, I am getting the error *"Unexpected token ; "*. I am comparing few things in the table and printing its value if it is greater than some value. It is similar to this code:

```
"var c = 4;
if (c &gt; 3) {
console.log(c); }"
```

Could someone help me out from this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try without encoding greater than ">" ?

Comment: if I use ">" then it will automatically convert it to "&gt;" and raises the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always emit your javascript in CDATA sections:

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[ 
var c = 4;
if (c > 3) {
  console.log(c); 
}
//]]>
</script>
```

That way they will be correctly handled while still making possible to use `${}` expressions inside your JS